# Assumptions for RotationMatrix

Tags: matrix, geometry, assumptions, rotation

I'm making C++ program, and in my program I need a rotation matrix around any vector. I wanted to extract `RotationMatrix[fi,{x,y,z}]` output and put it in my program. Unfortunately *Mathematica* thinks I operate with imaginary components (x,y,z). Because of that the output that I get is in epic dimensions xD.

I tried to fix this problem with `RotationMatrix[fi,{Re[x],Re[y],Re[z]}]` but no luck there. Apparently *Mathematica* doesn't track what type of variable the user defined (real/imaginary).

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: How about `FullSimplify[RotationMatrix[fi, {x, y, z}], 
 Assumptions -> {x \[Element] Reals, y \[Element] Reals, 
   z \[Element] Reals}]`?

Comment: Also take a look at [Rodrigues' rotation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula).

Comment: Sjoerd C. de Vries you are the MAN :)

Comment: Note, the the direct translation to C++ of Mathematica's matrix expression may not be efficient, maintainable and understandable. A production C++ implementation of Rodrigues rotation of a point about a vector is available at https://ceres-solver.googlesource.com/ceres-solver/+/master/include/ceres/rotation.h#587 as routine AngleAxisRotatePoint

Answer (score 8):

An even much faster way to accomplish this is:

```
ComplexExpand[RotationMatrix[fi, {x, y, z}], TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] // FullSimplify
```

Comment: 1+ Appreciated ;)

Answer (score 5):

One solution, as pointed out by Sjoerd, is to tell *Mathematica* that your variables are not complex.

```
FullSimplify[RotationMatrix[fi, {x, y, z}], {x, y, z} ∈ Reals]
```

This takes very long on my machine. Additionally, please note that it leads to undesired things in *Mathematica* version 8, because the result contains piecewise functions and `Conjugate` calls. To get the same result, you need to specify that the vector `{x, y, z}` does not vanish:

```
FullSimplify[RotationMatrix[fi, {x, y, z}],
             {x, y, z} ∈ Reals && ( x!=0 || y!=0 || z!=0 )]
```

Finally, on my machine it is much faster to first use `ComplexExpand` and then do the `FullSimplify` step:

```
FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[RotationMatrix[fi, {x, y, z}]], {x, y, z} ∈ Reals]
```

Comment: @Kuba Yes, you are right. I wanted to express that `{0,0,0}` is not allowed and wrote complete crap. Thanks for paying attention.

Comment: 1+ Appreciated ;)

Comment: `FullSimplify[RotationMatrix[fi,{x,y,z}],_∈Reals]`

Answer (score 5):

As noted by Rahul, one can always fall back on using the [Rodrigues rotation formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RodriguesRotationFormula.html) if need be:

```
rodrigues[th_, axis_?VectorQ] :=
  First[LinearAlgebra`Private`MatrixPolynomial[{{1, Sin[th], 2 Sin[th/2]^2}},
                                               -LeviCivitaTensor[3, List].Normalize[axis]]]
```

(In versions before 11.2, use `` LinearAlgebra`MatrixPolynomial[] ``.)

Comment: +1. This is quite fast compared to the other solutions. Also, I like the new avatar :)

Comment: It's what I was using way before the `*Transform[]` stuff came along (altho I was originally using `Array[Signature[{##}] &, {3, 3, 3}]` in place of what is now `LeviCivitaTensor[3]`.) And yes, this function was involved in my latest work of art. ;)