# Converting a rotation matrix to a quaternion

Tags: matrix, rotation, quaternions

I found a very good [link](http://blog.wolframalpha.com/2011/08/25/quaternion-properties-and-interactive-rotations-with-wolframalpha/) about quaternions in *Mathematica* , but I don't know how to create a quaternion from a rotation matrix. Can anyone help me, please?

#### Update

I need this:

> A rotation may be converted back to a quaternion through the use of the following algorithm. The process is performed in the following stages, which are as follows:
>
> Calculate the trace of the matrix T from the equation:

```
  T = 4 - 4x^2  - 4y^2  - 4z^2
    = 4( 1 - x^2  - y^2  - z^2 )
    = mat[0] + mat[5] + mat[10] + 1
```

> If the trace of the matrix is greater than zero, then perform an "instant" calculation.

```
  S = 0.5 / sqrt(T)
  W = 0.25 / S
  X = ( mat[9] - mat[6] ) * S
  Y = ( mat[2] - mat[8] ) * S
  Z = ( mat[4] - mat[1] ) * S
```

> If the trace of the matrix is less than or equal to zero then identify which major diagonal element has the greatest value.
>
> Depending on this value, calculate the following:
>
> Column 0:

```
    S  = sqrt( 1.0 + mr[0] - mr[5] - mr[10] ) * 2;
    Qx = 0.5 / S;
    Qy = (mr[1] + mr[4] ) / S;
    Qz = (mr[2] + mr[8] ) / S;
    Qw = (mr[6] + mr[9] ) / S;
```

> Column 1:

```
    S  = sqrt( 1.0 + mr[5] - mr[0] - mr[10] ) * 2;
    Qx = (mr[1] + mr[4] ) / S;
    Qy = 0.5 / S;
    Qz = (mr[6] + mr[9] ) / S;
    Qw = (mr[2] + mr[8] ) / S;
```

> Column 2:

```
    S  = sqrt( 1.0 + mr[10] - mr[0] - mr[5] ) * 2;
    Qx = (mr[2] + mr[8] ) / S;
    Qy = (mr[6] + mr[9] ) / S;
    Qz = 0.5 / S;
    Qw = (mr[1] + mr[4] ) / S;
```

> The quaternion is then defined as:

```
   Q = | Qx Qy Qz Qw |
```

Comment: Can you narrow the Q down ? Describe exactly what is the problem and include any relevant code.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand -- you write that you need this, and then you exhibit what you need.  What's missing from the algorithm you described in your update?

Answer (score 11):

If you are just asking how to use quaternions for rotation in *Mathematica*, I hope the following helps. You specify the axis with a unit vector and the angle of rotation. Here is one implementation:

```
Needs["Quaternions`"];

qr[vec_, u_, a_] := Module[{qv, qu, r},
   qv = ReplacePart[Join[{0}, vec], 0 -> Quaternion];
   qu = ReplacePart[Join[{Cos[a/2]}, Sin[a/2] Normalize[u]], 0 -> Quaternion];
   r = qu ** qv ** Conjugate[qu];
   N @ FullSimplify[ReplacePart[r, 0 -> List][[2 ;; 4]]]]
```

The first argument  of `qr` is the vector you rotate, the second argument is the axis, and the third argument is the angle of rotation.

Here is a visualization:

```
Manipulate[Graphics3D[
  {{Red, Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}]},
   {Blue, Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, qr[{1, 1, 1}, {m, n, p}, an Degree]}]},
   {Black, Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {m, n, p}}]},
   {Purple, Thickness[0.02], Line[Table[qr[{1, 1, 1}, {m, n, p}, j],
                                        {j, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/20}]]}}],
  {{an, 0}, 0, 360, AngularGauge[##, GaugeLabels -> {"Degrees", "Value"}] &, 
   ControlPlacement -> Left}, {m, 0.1, 1}, {n, 0.1, 1}, {p, 0.1, 1}]
```

[image: Manipulate]

Comment: May I ask: How did you make the .gif tracking your mouse movements etc.? Essentially a screen capture.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke I just use a freeware capture program: LICEcap: http://licecap.en.softonic.com/

Comment: Nice. Too bad it doesn't run under MacOS...

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke sorry

Comment: how can obtain only the quaternion. the output to be the quaternion,no that image. thanks

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke [LICEcap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/) DOES run on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 11):

I needed to do this recently, so I broke down and decided to write routines for interconverting quaternions and rotation matrices.

I'll give the quaternion to rotation matrix routine first, since it's the shortest. I merely needed to modify my Rodrigues routine in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/111693):

```
Needs["Quaternions`"];

quaternionToRotation[qq_] /; QuaternionQ[ToQuaternion[qq]] :=
    Module[{q = ToQuaternion[qq], aim, r},
           aim = AbsIJK[q]; r = Re[q];
           If[aim == 0, Return[IdentityMatrix[3], Module]];
           First[LinearAlgebra`Private`MatrixPolynomial[
                 {Prepend[2 aim {r, aim}/(r^2 + aim^2), 1]},
                 -LeviCivitaTensor[3, List].(Rest[List @@ q]/aim)]]]
```

(Use `` LinearAlgebra`MatrixPolynomial[] `` in versions before 11.2.)

Now, for the more complicated direction of converting a rotation matrix to a quaternion. I will provide two methods I found in the literature. This first one is due to [Markley](https://doi.org/10.2514/1.31730), which is a modification of an earlier method due to [Sheppard](https://doi.org/10.2514/3.55767)<sup>*</sup>:

```
rotationToQuaternion[m_?OrthogonalMatrixQ] := Module[{d, v, xm},
        d = Diagonal[m]; 
        v = {{m[[3, 2]] - m[[2, 3]], m[[1, 3]] - m[[3, 1]], m[[2, 1]] - m[[1, 2]]}};
        xm = IdentityMatrix[4] +
             DiagonalMatrix[{{1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, -1}, {-1, 1, -1}, {-1, -1, 1}}.d] + 
             ArrayFlatten[{{0, v}, {Transpose[v], 2 Symmetrize[m - DiagonalMatrix[d]]}}];
        Sign[Apply[Quaternion, First[MaximalBy[xm, Norm]]]]]
```

The second method I present is due to [Bar-Itzhack](https://doi.org/10.2514/2.4654):

```
rotationToQuaternion2[m_?OrthogonalMatrixQ] := Module[{d, v, xm},
        d = Diagonal[m]; 
        v = {{m[[3, 2]] - m[[2, 3]], m[[1, 3]] - m[[3, 1]], m[[2, 1]] - m[[1, 2]]}};
        xm = DiagonalMatrix[{{1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, -1}, {-1, 1, -1}, {-1, -1, 1}}.d] + 
             ArrayFlatten[{{0, v}, {Transpose[v], 2 Symmetrize[m - DiagonalMatrix[d]]}}];
        Sign[Apply[Quaternion, First[Eigenvectors[xm, 1]]]]]
```

(The observant reader ought to notice the similarities in the two methods.)

At this juncture, let me remind the leader that a quaternion $\mathbf q$ and its negative correspond to the same rotation. If needed, one can modify the conversion routines so that a quaternion with positive real part is always returned.

Now, for tests:

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42]; (* for reproducibility *)
            tstq = Apply[Quaternion, Normalize[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 4]]]];

Norm[rotationToQuaternion[quaternionToRotation[tstq]] + tstq]
   1.54074*10^-32

Norm[rotationToQuaternion2[quaternionToRotation[tstq]] - tstq]
   3.08149*10^-32

BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42]; (* for reproducibility *)
            tst = Orthogonalize[# Det[#]] &[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {3, 3}]]];

Norm[quaternionToRotation[rotationToQuaternion[tst]] - tst]
   5.23541*10^-16

Norm[quaternionToRotation[rotationToQuaternion2[tst]] - tst]
   2.37306*10^-16
```

---

* - altho it may not look it, the article by Sheppard is at the end of the PDF from that link.

---

**Update 9/15/2019**

An even faster and more accurate method due to [Sarabandi, Perez-Gracia, and Thomas](http://www.iri.upc.edu/people/thomas/papers/AGACSE2018.pdf), based on the Cayley representation of the rotation matrix, can be very simply implemented in *Mathematica*:

```
rotationToQuaternionCayley[m_?OrthogonalMatrixQ] := 
          With[{s = {{m[[3, 2]] - m[[2, 3]], m[[1, 3]] - m[[3, 1]], m[[2, 1]] - m[[1, 2]]},
                     {0, m[[2, 1]] + m[[1, 2]], m[[1, 3]] + m[[3, 1]]},
                     {0, 0, m[[3, 2]] + m[[2, 3]]}}},
               Apply[Quaternion, Prepend[Sign[First[s]], 1]
               Map[Norm, DiagonalMatrix[Prepend[NestList[RotateRight, {1, -1, -1}, 2],
                                                {1, 1, 1}].Diagonal[m] + 1] +
                         ((# + Transpose[#]) &[PadLeft[s, {-4, 4}]])]/4]]
```

Comment: (Relatedly, see [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29924) for routines to derive the axis-angle representation of a rotation matrix.)