# How to rotate 3D ellipsoid with built-in functions?

Tags: graphics3d, rotation

I have 3D graphics with an ellipsoid and three arrows which represent its axes. However, not all arrows are inside the ellipsoid; two are outside. How can I rotate the ellipsoid with the use of built-in functions to have the arrows inside the ellipsoid? I have tried three different solutions; however, none give the result I want to get. What did I do wrong?

Here is an example:

```
Module[{rotZ, a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, l1, l2, l3},
{a1, a2, a3} = {{1.5, 0., 0.}, {0., 1, 0.}, {0., 0., 2}};
rotZ[θ_] := {{Cos[θ], Sin[θ], 0}, {-Sin[θ], Cos[θ], 0}, {0, 0, 1}};
{b1, b2, b3} = {rotZ[30. Degree].a1, rotZ[30. Degree].a2, a3};
{l1, l2, l3} = Map[Sqrt[#[[1]]^2 + #[[2]]^2 + #[[3]]^2] &, {a1, a2, a3}];
Graphics3D[{
(*coodrinate system*)      
{Arrowheads[Small], Arrow[{{0., 0., 0.}, {1., 0., 0.}}]}, 
Text[Style["X", 12, Black],  {1., 0., 0.} 1.1],
{Arrowheads[Small], Arrow[{{0., 0., 0.}, {0., 1., 0.}}]}, 
Text[Style["Y", 12, Black], {0., 1., 0.} 1.1],
{Arrowheads[Small], Arrow[{{0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 1.}}]}, 
Text[Style["Z", 12, Black], {0., 0., 1.} 1.1],
{Dotted, Line[{{0., 0., 0.}, {-1., 0., 0.}}]}, {Dotted, 
Line[{{0., 0., 0.}, {0., -1., 0.}}]}, {Dotted, 
Line[{{0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., -1}}]},
(*ellipsoid*)
(*1*)
{Opacity[0.3], Gray, Ellipsoid[{0., 0., 0.}, {l1, l2, l3}]},
(*2*)
(*{Opacity[0.3],Gray,Ellipsoid[{0.,0.,0.},{b1,b2,b3}]},*)
(*3*)
(*{Opacity[0.3],Gray,Rotate[Ellipsoid[{0.,0.,0.},{l1,l2,l3}],
30. Degree,{0.,0.,0.}]},*)
(*ellipsoid axes*)
{Arrowheads[Small], Arrow[{{0., 0., 0.}, b1}]}, 
Text[Style["a1", 12, Black], b1 1.1],
{Arrowheads[Small], Arrow[{{0., 0., 0.}, b2}]}, 
Text[Style["a2", 12, Black], b2 1.1], {Arrowheads[Small], 
Arrow[{{0., 0., 0.}, b3}]}, Text[Style["a3", 12, Black], b3 1.1]
}, ViewPoint -> Top
]]
```

Answer (score 9):

`TransformedRegion[]` can quickly determine the rotated ellipsoid:

```
er[θ_] = TransformedRegion[Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {4, 3, 2}],
                           RotationTransform[θ, {0, 0, 1}]]
```

which yields

```
   Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {{16 Cos[θ]^2 + 9 Sin[θ]^2, 7 Cos[θ] Sin[θ], 0},
                         {7 Cos[θ] Sin[θ], 9 Cos[θ]^2 + 16 Sin[θ]^2, 0},
                         {0, 0, 4}}]
```

Alternatively, you can directly construct the rotated `Ellipsoid[]` with `RotationMatrix[]`:

```
er[θ_] := Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, RotationMatrix[θ, {0, 0, 1}].DiagonalMatrix[{4, 3, 2}^2].
                               RotationMatrix[-θ, {0, 0, 1}]]
```

Note the arrangement of the matrices in the second argument of `Ellipsoid[]`; in this, you are in effect performing a *similarity transformation* on the diagonal matrix containing the squares of the semiaxis lengths. Similar arrangements will work for other rotation (or orthogonal in general) matrices.

Thus,

```
With[{θ = -30 ​°}, 
     Graphics3D[{Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {4, 3, 2}],
                 {Opacity[2/3, Red], er[θ]}}]]
```

[image: ellipsoid and its rotated version]

---

As a more elaborate example, let's rotate an ellipsoid about an arbitrary axis:

```
(* https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/111693 *)
rodrigues[th_, axis_?VectorQ] :=
         First[LinearAlgebra`MatrixPolynomial[{{1, Sin[th], 2 Sin[th/2]^2}},
                                              -LeviCivitaTensor[3, List].Normalize[axis]]]

ela[θ_, ax_] := With[{m = rodrigues[θ, ax]},
    Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, m.DiagonalMatrix[{4, 3, 2}^2].Transpose[m]]]

With[{ax = {3, -2, 4}}, 
     Animate[Graphics3D[{Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {4, 3, 2}],
                         {Opacity[2/3, Red],
                          Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, 5 Normalize[ax]}, 0.05]], 
                          ela[θ, ax]}}, Boxed -> False, PlotRange -> 5],
             {θ, 0, 2 π - π/20, π/20}]]
```

[image: ellipsoid rotated about an arbitrary axis]

Answer (score 1):

I guess there was a question of the definition of the sign in your rotation matrix?

If you use the following:

```
{Opacity[0.3], Gray, Rotate[Ellipsoid[{0., 0., 0.}, {l1, l2, l3}], -30 Degree, {0, 0, 1}]}
```

I get your ellipsoid axes (`a1`, `a2`, `a3`) to align with the ellipse.

In the *Mathematica* documentation ([here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RotationMatrix.html)) you will see that the negative sign is oppositely defined compared to your rotation matrix. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, it helps. Thank you.