# How to transform general Ellipsoid into rotated axis-oriented one?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, geometry, conversion, geometric-transform

Recently, I discovered a [long-standing bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/163872/280) in the rendering of `Disk` and `Circle` primitives after applying `GeometricTransformation` with a matrix as the second argument. This bug affects rendering of general ellipsoids of the form `Ellipsoid[p, Σ]`, but does not affect axes-oriented ellipsoids of the form `Ellipsoid[p, {r1, …}]`, because the latter are directly translated into the corresponding `Disk` objects with the same syntax and arguments. Applying `Rotate` (or `GeometricTransformation` with `RotationTransform` as the second argument) to the axis-oriented ellipsoids is a workaround for the bug. But for this we should be able to obtain from the matrix `Σ` the corresponding semiaxes lengths `{r1, …}` and the rotation angle `Θ` (for the 3D case, we also need the rotation axis `w`).

There is an elegant and efficient built-in way to perform the opposite task. For the 2D case, we have:

```
TransformedRegion[Ellipsoid[{x, y}, {r1, r2}], RotationTransform[Θ, {x, y}]]
```

> ```
> Ellipsoid[{x, y}, 
>    {{r1^2 Cos[Θ]^2 + r2^2 Sin[Θ]^2, r1^2 Cos[Θ] Sin[Θ] - r2^2 Cos[Θ] Sin[Θ]}, 
>     {r1^2 Cos[Θ] Sin[Θ]] - r2^2 Cos[Θ] Sin[Θ], r2^2 Cos[Θ]^2 + r1^2 Sin[Θ]^2}}]
> ```

But I failed to find a way to transform `Ellipsoid[p, Σ]` into `Rotate[Ellipsoid[p, {r1, …}], Θ, p]` (or another suitable syntax form of `Rotate` or `RotationTransform`). **Is it possible to do this in an elegant and efficient way** (2D and 3D cases)**?**

Comment: Related: "[Axis/Angle from rotation matrix](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29924/280)."

Comment: [A related question.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/138154)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can employ `Eigensystem` in order to find the principal axes. While the rotation angle can be easily found in 2D case, the 3D case involves also the detection of the rotation axis; this is done by utilizing `NullSpace`.

**2D case**

```
SeedRandom[666];
Σ = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2, 2}];
Σ = Transpose[Σ].Σ;
p = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2}]; 

{λ, U} = Eigensystem[Σ];
r = Sqrt[λ];
rot = Det[U] Transpose[U];
θ = ArcTan @@ (rot[[All, 1]]);
Max[Abs[RotationMatrix[θ] - rot]]
Graphics[{
  FaceForm[ColorData[97][2]], Ellipsoid[p, Σ],
  EdgeForm[{Thickness[0.015], ColorData[97][1]}], 
  Rotate[#, θ, p] &@Ellipsoid[p, r]
  }]
```

> 0.

[image]

**3D case**

```
SeedRandom[666];
Σ = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {3, 3}];
Σ = Transpose[Σ].Σ;
p = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {3}];    

{λ, U} = Eigensystem[Σ];
r = Sqrt[λ];
rot = Det[U] Transpose[U];
w = NullSpace[rot - IdentityMatrix[3]][[1]];
V = RotationMatrix[{{1, 0, 0}, w}];
θ = -ArcTan @@ (Transpose[V].rot.V)[[2, 2 ;; 3]];
Max[Abs[RotationMatrix[θ, w] - rot]]
Show[
 Graphics3D[{
   FaceForm[ColorData[97][2]], 
   Ellipsoid[p, Σ],
   ColorData[97][1],
   Rotate[#, θ, w, p] &@Ellipsoid[p, r]
   }, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
 ]
```

> 7.77156*10^-16

[image]

Since `RotationMatrix` is the bottleneck here, I also link to [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/161230/how-to-speed-up-rotationmatrix/161232#161232) of mine.

Comment: My previous (deleted) comment was a consequence of wrong test due to non-fresh kernel, sorry for that. Actually you solution can be generalized for arbitrary position of ellipsoid as simple as adding fourth argument to `Rotate`: `Rotate[Ellipsoid[p, r], θ, w, p]`.

Comment: Oh, that's good to know!