# How to get rotate angle θ of rotated ellipse?

Tags: geometry, rotation

I have ellipse function as below:

```
−3.06274 x^2 − y^2 + 1192.22 x + 152.71 y + 1.829648 x y − 196494 == 0
```

This ellipse looks like:
[image: ellipse]

How to get the rotate angle of this rotated ellipse?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/163880/how-to-transform-general-ellipsoid-into-rotated-axis-oriented-one/163893#163893).  You only have to find $\Sigma$ and $p$ by [completing the square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square).

Comment: I think there's a mathematica function can help me to transform the function to complete the square.but I cannot find it.

Comment: You could get the `EigenVectors` of your ellipse and then use the dot product...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nasser already gave you a solution. There is a different approach though where I used nothing more than the basic knowledge, that an ellipse can be represented by

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}-val=0$$

and you said in the comments, that you are seeking a quadratic form. Your example shows that the ellipse is shifted and rotated. Let us transform the x and y in the above equation and introduce a shift and a rotation. We use mx and my as translation and phi as rotation and this can be represented by a matrix multiplication

```
RotationMatrix[phi].{x - mx, y - my}
```

Now we replace our original x and y with this result

```
expr = x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 - val /. Thread[{x, y} -> RotationMatrix[phi].{x - mx, y - my}]
```

We get

$$\frac{((x-\text{mx}) \cos (\phi )-(y-\text{my}) \sin (\phi
   ))^2}{a^2}+\frac{((x-\text{mx}) \sin (\phi )+(y-\text{my}) \cos (\phi
   ))^2}{b^2}-\text{val}$$

You can use

```
expr // ExpandAll
```

to see all terms. What you should notice is that we have positive terms for y^2 in the form

```
(y^2 Sin[phi]^2)/a^2
```

because the sine-squared will always be positive and a^2 too. In your example those terms have a negative coefficient. Since it is an equation, we can simply multiply with -1 to turn everything around

```
example = (-3.06274*x^2 - y^2 + 1192.22*x + 152.71*y + 1.829648*x*y - 196494)*-1
```

If you look at the expanded form of `expr` and the form of your example, you can see that we can now compare coefficients:

```
eq = Thread[Flatten /@ (CoefficientList[example, {x, y}] == 
      CoefficientList[expr, {x, y}])];
eq // Column
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

When I counted correctly, we have 6 valid equations for 6 parameters `mx`, `my`, `a`, `b`, `phi`, and `val`. Let us try to solve this

```
sol = Solve[eq, {mx, my, a, b, phi, val}];
sol // Column
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Here, you have the full set of solutions (if I'm not mistaken). You see that they mainly differ in a, b, and phi. Thinking about it, this can be easily explained. First, when there are only `a^2` and `b^2` in the equation, both `a` and `-a` are valid solutions. Second, you can have ellipses with larger `a` or larger `b`, they only need to be rotated differently. This mix gives the different solutions that are all valid.

Let's test the first solution by replacing the values in our original `expr`

```
expr /. sol[[1]] // Expand
(* 196494. - 1192.22 x + 3.06274 x^2 - 152.71 y - 1.82965 x y + 1. y^2 *)
```

As you can see, we get your original example. The last solution has a phi value of 0.362 which is in degree

```
phi/(2 Pi)*360 /. sol[[-1]]
(* 20.7865 *)
```

the same value that Nasser calculated. Finally, if you want to see the quadratic form, you can use this:

```
With[{e = expr},
 HoldForm[e] /. sol[[-1]]
]
```

$$\frac{((-350.067+y) \cos (0.362793)+(-299.196+x) \sin (0.362793))^2}{1.23774^2}+\frac{((-299.196+x) \cos (0.362793)-(-350.067+y) \sin (0.362793))^2}{0.54153^2}-8589.02$$

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this (with J.M.'s shortening of the code):

```
quad = Last@ CoefficientArrays[
    -3.06274 x^2 - y^2 + 1192.22 x + 152.71 y + 1.829648 x y - 196494,
    {x, y}, "Symmetric" -> True];
ev = Eigenvectors@quad;
Mod[ArcTan @@@ ev, Pi]

(*  {2.7788, 1.208}  *)
```

Comment: You can do `Last[CoefficientArrays[-3.06274 x^2 - y^2 + 1192.22 x + 152.71 y + 1.829648 x y - 196494, {x, y}, "Symmetric" -> True]]` instead to directly get a symmetric matrix.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks. I hadn't noticed that option. Best wishes

Answer (score 2):

The angle is given by `1/2 ArcCot[(a - c)/(2 b)]` when writing the general conic section as $a x^2+ 2 b x y + c y^2+ 2 d x+2 f y+g =0$ Hence in this case

```
3.06274 x^2 - y^2 + 1192.22 x + 152.71 y + 1.829648 x y - 196494=0;
```

The angle is `-20.78` degree.

Use  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ellipse.html

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Since in this case $c=-1$ and $a=-3.06274$.
To verify, here is a manipulate, which plots the original `-3.06274*x^2 - y^2 + 1192.22*x + 152.71*y + 1.829648*x*y - 196494 == 0` as `ContourPlot` then plots the standard ellipse equation when rotated, which is

$$
\frac{  ((x-x_0) \cos \alpha  + (y-y_0) \sin\alpha)^2}{a^2} + \frac{  ((x-x_0) \sin \alpha  - (y-y_0) \cos\alpha)^2}{b^2}=1
$$

Using the angle of rotation $\alpha$ found from `1/2 ArcCot[(a - c)/(2 b)]` and using `a` and `b` found per

[image: Mathematica graphics]

From http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ellipse.html

The center $x_0$ and $y_0$ are given by

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This shows exact fit. The red color is the `ContourPlot` using your general conic and the black ellipse is using the rotation angle.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
g1 = ContourPlot[-3.06274*x^2 - y^2 + 1192.22*x + 152.71*y + 
     1.829648*x*y - 196494 == 0, {x, 200, 500}, {y, 200, 500}, 
   ContourStyle -> Red, Frame -> False]; 

eq = -3.06274*x^2 - y^2 + 1192.22*x + 152.71*y + 1.829648*x*y - 196494; 
(*reading from the above gives *)
a = -3.06274; 
b = 1.829648/2; 
c = -1; 
d = 1192.22/2; 
f = 152.71/2; 
g = -196494; 

(*see Wolfram Mathworld for derivation*)
a0 = Sqrt[(2*(a*f^2 + c*d^2 + g*b^2 - 2*b*d*f - a*c*g))/((b^2 - 
        a*c)*(Sqrt[(a - c)^2 + 4*b^2] - (a + c)))]; 
b0 = Sqrt[(2*(a*f^2 + c*d^2 + g*b^2 - 2*b*d*f - a*c*g))/((b^2 - 
        a*c)*(-Sqrt[(a - c)^2 + 4*b^2] - (a + c)))]; 
x0 = (c d - b f)/(b^2 - a c);
y0 = (a f - b d)/(b^2 - a c);

(*compare to given conic*)
Manipulate[Module[{z = ang*(180/Pi), g2, x, y}, 

  g2 = ContourPlot[((x - x0)*Cos[z] + (y - y0)*Sin[z])^2/
       a^2 + ((x - x0)*Sin[z] - (y - y0)*Cos[z])^2/b^2 == 1, {x, 100, 
     500}, {y, 100, 600}, ContourStyle -> Black]; 

  Graphics[{First[g2], First[g1]},PlotRange -> {{100, 600}, {100, 600}}, Axes -> True]], 

 {{a, 50.18738140246613, "a"}, 50, 200, 0.01,Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 {{b, 114.71032896005666, "b"}, 40, 130, 0.01,Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 {{ang, -20.786494338349772, "angle"}, -40, 90, 0.1,Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get all parameters of that ellipse in a quite mechanical way.

The normal ellipse equation is

```
eli[x_, y_, a_, b_] = x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 - 1 == 0
```

to rotate the ellipse, apply this rule

```
rotate[phi_] := 
   Thread[{x,y} -> {{Cos[phi], -Sin[phi]}, {Sin[phi], Cos[phi]}}.{x, y}]
```

To move the center apply

```
move[c_, d_] := Thread[{x, y} -> {x - c, y - d}]

ContourPlot[
   Evaluate[eli[x, y, 50, 120] /. rotate[20 Degree] /. 
   move[300, 350]], {x, 200, 400}, {y, 200, 500}, MaxRecursion -> 8]
```

[image]

In order to find all parameters, first find y to given x in your ellipse

```
sol = First@
       Solve[\[Minus]3.06274 x^2 \[Minus] y^2 + 1192.22 x + 152.71 y + 
         1.829648 x y \[Minus] 196494 == 0, y, Reals] // Quiet
```

Generate five equations with five given x-values {250, 260, 270, 280, 290}

```
equ = (((First[eli[x, y, a, b]] /. rotate[phi] /. 
      move[c, d]) == -196494 + 1192.22` x - 3.06274` x^2 + 
     152.71` y + 1.829648` x y - y^2) /. sol /. x -> #) & /@ {250,
260, 270, 280, 290}
```

Use FindRoot to find all parameters.

```
FindRoot[equ, {{a, 50}, {b, 120}, {c, 300}, {d, 350}, {phi, 20}}]

(* {a -> 50.1874, b -> 114.71, c -> 299.196, d -> 350.067, phi -> 20.7865} *)
```