# Incomplete ellipse due to StreamPlot command

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, scaling

I wrote the following in Mathematica code but the result was not the expected.  As you can see it seems like just half of an elipse is there, what can I do to see the complete elipse?

```
StreamPlot[{2 A (1 - .0001 A) - .01 A L, -.5 L + .0001 A L}, {A, 0, 
1000}, {L, 0, 1000}]
```

[image]

Comment: I also tried to modify the A and L range but still, no complete elipse.

Comment: Never use upper-case letters to start the name of a variable in *Mathematica* as it is likely to conflict with internal names.

Comment: Why do you think there should be a full ellipse?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I used upper-case letter because that's how was written in the DE model. But for the next time i'll use lower-case letters.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork intuition, why should not it be an ellipse or a circle? Why just half? :)

Comment: Because the range must be full and both positive and negative values be included.  Try plotting a *full* ellipse...

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Doesn't work either. Now I have to half ellipses, one in the first quadrant and the other in the second quadrant.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as David already pointed out you haven't explained why you think it should resemble an ellipse. You can take an ellipse equation and calculate the partial derivatives and rotate them by 90 degrees:

```
ellipse = x^2/8 + y^2/2 - 1;
RotationMatrix[Pi/2].(D[ellipse, #] & /@ {x, y})

StreamPlot[%, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Since your working with DE anyway, you might know that this is equivalent to taking the `Curl`

```
Curl[ellipse, {x, y}]
(* {-y, x/4} *)
```

Now, do the same for the generalized ellipse I gave in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/164249/187) in `expr` and calculate the curl. If you expand everything, you see that there is no term that contains `x^2` or `x*y`. Your example however contains such terms. Again, why do you think this should be an ellipse?

Comment: Is not an ellipse then?

Comment: @Anneliset. Look, you present something and you claim it should give an ellipse in the vector plot. Everyone says, why you think this should be the case. I show you, how you can get the general form of such an ellipse vector field and that your example does not have the same form. Everyone really tries to help, although the tone is sometimes very *direct*. We cannot guess what you try to do and my answer should have shown you, how you can create the vector field of an ellipse. I *assumed* that since you have `A^2` a `AL` terms in your form, you somehow only took the ellipse equation..

Comment: .. and tried to put it into `StreamPlot`, but I can only make wild guesses. You have to clear the situation.

Comment: I see, perhaps I should not have claim that it is an ellipse, as I said before my intuition made me think about an ellipse or something circular.