# Meaning of arguments in FittedModels`ParameterEllipsoid

Tags: fitting, nonlinear, undocumented

I am trying to figure out what `` FittedModels`ParameterEllipsoid ``'s parameters mean (I want to construct a filled ellipse)

Here is a minimum working example:

```
data = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 1}, {4, 0}};
model = a + b x^2;
nlfit = NonlinearModelFit[data, model, {a, b}, x];

nlfit["ParameterConfidenceRegion"]
```

returns:

> `` FittedModels`ParameterEllipsoid[{1.0069,-0.0344828},{2.60148,0.215202},{{-0.996379,0.0850249},{-0.0850249,-0.996379}}] ``

Graphically spelunking to find what those parameters mean:

```
Graphics[
 {
  nlfit["ParameterConfidenceRegion"],
  PointSize[0.01],
  Blue,
  Text["P1", p1 = {1.0068, -0.0344}],
  Orange,
  Text["P2", p2 = {2.6014, 0.215202}],
  Red,
  Text["P3", p3 = {-0.9963, 0.0850}],
  Magenta,
  Text["P4", p4 = {-0.0850, -0.9963}]      
  },
 Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: ellipse and points]

The first point is likely the ellipse center. The third point might be one of the foci.

I tried investigating where the second and fourth points come from.  They look like normals because their magnitude is about 1–but nothing obvious pops up, and
`Normalize[(p3 - p1)]`
doesn't return `p4` or `p2`.

What do the parameters of `` FittedModels`ParameterEllipsoid[a, b, {c, d}] ``
mean?

Comment: I would bet that `{{-0.996379, 0.0850249}, {-0.0850249, -0.996379}}` is a rotation matrix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Addition:**  At the end I've added how the ellipse is created in a more direct manner.

Copying from @Akku14 's answer ([How to get rotate angle θ of rotated ellipse?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/164230/how-to-get-rotate-angle-%ce%b8-of-rotated-ellipse)), the following might be what's needed:

```
data = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 1}, {4, 0}}
model = a + b x^2
nlfit = NonlinearModelFit[data, model, {a, b}, x]
pcr = nlfit["ParameterConfidenceRegion"]

eli[x_, y_, a_, b_] = x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 - 1 == 0
rotate = Thread[{x, y} -> pcr[[3]] . {x, y}]
Show[ContourPlot[Evaluate[eli[x, y, pcr[[2, 1]], pcr[[2, 2]]] /. rotate /. 
  Thread[{x, y} -> {x - pcr[[1, 1]], y - pcr[[1, 2]]}]], 
  {x, -2, 4}, {y, -0.4, 0.3}, 
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 18, Italic] &) /@ {"a", "b"}],
ListPlot[{pcr[[1]]}]]
```

[image: 95% confidence ellipse for parameters a and b]

**Direct calculation of an approximate confidence ellipse for any two parameters in a model**

```
n = Length[data];  (* Number of data points *)
p = 2;  (* Number of parameters in model *)
i1 = 1;  (* Indices of two parameters for joint confidence ellipse *)
i2 = 2;  (* Note in this example there are only two parameters *)
cov = nlfit["CovarianceMatrix"];  (* Covariance matrix for all parameters *)
(* Get the covariance matrix of the two parameters of interest *)
cov = {{cov[[i1, i1]], cov[[i1, i2]]}, {cov[[i1, i2]], cov[[i2, i2]]}};
estimates = nlfit["BestFitParameters"];  (* Parameter estimates *)

(* Ellipse for all confidence levels *)
ellipse = ((({a, b} - {aTrue, bTrue}) . Inverse[cov] . ({a, b} - {aTrue, bTrue})) /. estimates);

(* Contour value for approximate confidence ellipse *)
confLevel = 0.95;  (* 95% confidence level *)
c = InverseCDF[FRatioDistribution[2, n - p - 1], confLevel];

Show[ContourPlot[ellipse, {aTrue, -2, 4}, {bTrue, -0.4, 0.3}, 
  Contours -> {c}, ContourShading -> None, 
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 18, Italic] &) /@ {"a", "b"}],
 ListPlot[{{a, b} /. estimates}]]
```

[image: 95% confidence ellipse]

This also works for `LinearModelFit` and `GeneralizedLinearModelFit`.   Something nearly identical can be done for a confidence ellipsoid for 3 parameters.  For 4 parameters you need magic mushrooms or drop acid to visualize the ellipsoid.

Comment: That’s it. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

It is indeed (the inverse of) a rotation matrix, as mentioned by @JimB.

```
{center, semiaxes, matrix} = List @@ nlfit["ParameterConfidenceRegion"];

Graphics[{
  Yellow, GeometricTransformation[Ellipsoid[{0, 0}, semiaxes], {Inverse@matrix, center}], 
  Red, ellipse}, Axes -> True
]
```

[image]