# Perplexing simplification of RotationMatrix

Tags: simplifying-expressions, rotation

The result of

```
FullSimplify[RotationMatrix[θ, {Cos[ψ], Sin[ψ], 0}], ψ > 0].{0, 0, 1}
```

in Mathematica 11 is

```
{Sign[Sec[ψ]]^2 Sin[θ] Sin[ψ], -Cos[ψ] Sin[θ], Cos[θ]}
```

instead of the nicer result given by

```
EulerMatrix[{ψ, θ, 0}, {3, 1, 3}].{0, 0, 1}
```

which is

```
{Sin[θ] Sin[ψ], -Cos[ψ] Sin[θ], Cos[θ]}
```

Using just `Simplify` instead of `FullSimplify` gives an even more complex result: (yes I know this is expected, I've just put it here for completeness)

```
{(Sec[ψ] Sin[θ] Tan[ψ])/Abs[Sec[ψ]]^2, -((Sec[ψ] Sin[θ])/Abs[Sec[ψ]]^2), Cos[θ]}
```

How does one *generically* get around this simplification issue with `RotationMatrix`?

Comment: Related: [Assumptions for RotationMatrix](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32153/assumptions-for-rotationmatrix).

Comment: You could help the system out with assumptions such as `Sec[\[Psi]] > 0 || Sec[\[Psi]] < 0`

Comment: Yes but that's specific to this problem -- it's very much like simplifying by hand. I'm looking for a more generic solution. I've emphasized the _generic_ now.

Comment: Well, you need to help it out somehow; surely you don't need the angles to span more than $[0,2\pi)$, no?

Comment: I think any useful solution will make use of some of the specific characteristics of your problem. Perhaps you can add more details on the class of problems you need to handle.

Comment: There seem to be two points on which Mathematica stumbles: 1. Understand that `Sec[z] != 0` for any `z` 2. Understand that `Sign[x]^2 == 1` if `x!=0` (it can only do this we specify `x>0 || x<0` instead of the equivalent `x!=0`).   You'll have to help it through these two somehow.

Comment: @Szabolcs, actually I don't have a more complex problem at the moment (but I anticipate I may have one in the future). I just asked this question as it might be useful to someone else (including possibly future me). Should I delete the question?

Comment: No need to delete, I think ...

Answer (score 2):

To work around the lack of simplification of the [`Sign`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sign) term, you could try adding [`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand) as a transformation function (this will tacitly assume that all variables are real):

```
FullSimplify[
    RotationMatrix[θ, {Cos[ψ],Sin[ψ],0}],
    TransformationFunctions->{Automatic,ComplexExpand[#,TargetFunctions->{Re,Im}]&}
] . {0,0,1}
```

> {Sin[θ] Sin[ψ], -Cos[ψ] Sin[θ], Cos[θ]}