# 2D and 3D graphics that project a world map on Icosahedron

Tags: graphics3d, geometry, geographics, polyhedra, textures

I would like to generate 2D and 3D graphics of icosahedron with continuous world map projected on them. An example is provided as follows:

[image: Example of 2D and 3D Icosahedron with world map as texture]

It's trivial to generate 3D Icosahedron using `GraphicsComplex`. We can add texture. However, I am not sure how to add the continuous texture on it. Anyone has suggestions? Many thanks!

Answer (score 8):

[image]

Slightly changed last example from docs on [GeoProjection](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoProjection.html). There are a few issues, for instance textures have different resolution. If I figure things out I'lll update the answer. But I thought this is a good start for you anyway.

```
PolyhedronProjection[polyhedron_]:=
Module[{pts3D,center,pts2D,proj,pts2Dprojected,geographics,plotrange,pts2Dscaled,rescale},
rescale[{x_,y_},{xs_,ys_}]:={Rescale[x,xs],Rescale[y,ys]};
Graphics3D[{
pts3D=First[#];
center=Mean[pts3D];
center=GeoPosition[GeoPositionXYZ[center,Norm[center]]];
pts2D=GeoPosition[GeoPositionXYZ[pts3D,Norm[pts3D[[1]]]]];
proj={"Gnomonic","Centering"->center};
pts2Dprojected=Most/@GeoGridPosition[pts2D,proj][[1]];
geographics=GeoGraphics[{Opacity[0],center,GeoPath[pts2D[[1]],
    CurveClosed->True]},GeoProjection->proj,GeoZoomLevel->1,
    GeoBackground->"CountryBorders"];
plotrange=PlotRange/.AbsoluteOptions[geographics,PlotRange];
pts2Dscaled=rescale[#,plotrange]&/@pts2Dprojected;
{Texture[ImageData[Rasterize[geographics[[1]],"Image"]]],
Polygon[pts3D,VertexTextureCoordinates->pts2Dscaled]}}&/@
N@Flatten[PolyhedronData[polyhedron,"Faces","Polygon"]],
Boxed->False,SphericalRegion->True]]


PolyhedronProjection["Icosahedron"]
```

Answer (score 6):

~ 6 years ago, I wrote a little routine for [gnomonically projecting](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GnomonicProjection.html) a spherical texture onto a polyhedron:

```
(* Newell's algorithm for face normals *)
newellNormals[pts_List?MatrixQ] := With[{tp = Transpose[pts]}, 
      Normalize[MapThread[Dot, {ListConvolve[{{-1, 1}}, tp, {{2, -1}, {2, -1}}], 
                                ListConvolve[{{1, 1}}, tp, {{-2, -1}, {-2, -1}}]}]]]

(* https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/167114 *)
    vectorRotate[vv1_?VectorQ, vv2_?VectorQ] := 
     Module[{v1 = Normalize[vv1], v2 = Normalize[vv2], c, d, d1, d2, t1, t2},
            d = v1.v2;
            If[TrueQ[Chop[1 + d] == 0],
               c = UnitVector[3, First[Ordering[Abs[v1], 1]]];
               t1 = c - v1; t2 = c - v2; d1 = t1.t1; d2 = t2.t2;
               IdentityMatrix[3] - 2 (Outer[Times, t2, t2]/d2 - 
               2 t2.t1 Outer[Times, t2, t1]/(d2 d1) + Outer[Times, t1, t1]/d1),
               c = Cross[v1, v2];
               d IdentityMatrix[3] + Outer[Times, c, c]/(1 + d) - LeviCivitaTensor[3].c]]

Options[polyhedronProjection] = {Padding -> 1., Resampling -> Automatic};
polyhedronProjection[Polygon[pts_?MatrixQ], img_Image, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
    Module[{eps = 0.05, h, ptp, tex, trf, tri},
           tri = AffineTransform[{vectorRotate[{0, 0, 1}, newellNormals[pts]], 
                                  Mean[pts]}];
           trf = InverseFunction[tri];
           ptp = Drop[trf /@ pts, None, -1]; h = Max[Abs[ptp]];
           tex = ImageTransformation[img, 
                                     If[Graphics`PolygonUtils`InPolygonQ[(1 + eps) ptp, #], 
                                        Function[{x, y, z},
                                                 {Arg[x + I y], ArcSin[z] + π/2}] @@ 
                                        Normalize[tri[Append[#, 0.]]], -{4, 1}] &, 
                                     AspectRatio -> Automatic,
                                     DataRange -> {{-π, π}, {0, π}},
                                     PlotRange -> {{-h, h}, {-h, h}}, 
                                     Sequence @@ FilterRules[{opts} ~Join~
                                                          Options[polyhedronProjection], 
                                                          Options[ImageTransformation]]];
           {Texture[tex],
            Polygon[pts, VertexTextureCoordinates -> Rescale[ptp, {-h, h}]]}]
```

Using, for instance, the [ETOPO1 global relief](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/global/),

```
etopo1 = Import["http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/image/color_etopo1_ice_low.jpg"];
```

we can do the following:

```
ico = First @ Normal[MapAt[ScalingTransform[{1, 1, 1}/
                                            PolyhedronData["Icosahedron", "Circumradius"]], 
                           N[PolyhedronData["Icosahedron", "GraphicsComplex"]], 1]];

Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], polyhedronProjection[#, etopo1] & /@ ico}, 
           Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image: icosahedral world]

The method works for any polyhedron that can be inscribed in a unit sphere. For example, one of my previous Gravatars was based on `"TruncatedIcosahedron"`:

[image: Buckyworld]

See [this reference](https://doi.org/10.2307/209914) as well.

---

However, I have not been successful in modifying this method so that it can be used on the result of `PolyhedronData["Icosahedron", "Net"]`; I'd be interested in seeing someone else do so.

Additionally, there are other possible projections of a sphere onto a polyhedron. [Snyder](https://doi.org/10.3138/27H7-8K88-4882-1752) devised an equal-area map projection, while [Lee](https://doi.org/10.3138/FQ88-5827-6550-4144) gives a conformal projection onto the dodecahedron, which can be mapped onto an icosahedron as well by virtue of duality. I'll leave all those for someone else to do.