# Vectors do not define a plane when constructing a RotationMatrix

Tags: matrix, rotation

The following code:

```
RotationMatrix[{{0, 1, 0}, {0, -1, 0}}]
```

Gives an assertion message:

```
RotationMatrix::spln: Vectors {0,1,0} and {0,-1,0} do not define a plane.
```

Why can I define a `RotationMatrix` in this way?

**Edit** I found the reason in here: [Calculate Rotation Matrix to align Vector A to Vector B](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180418/calculate-rotation-matrix-to-align-vector-a-to-vector-b-in-3d), this is caused by the dot product of two vectors is -1,then the equation is divided by 0.

Comment: Your vectors are colinear, so do not define a unique rotation axis.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit**

Another way is use perturbation.

```
u = {0, 1, 0};
v = {0, -1, 0};
m = Limit[RotationMatrix[{u, v + t*RandomInteger[20, 3]}], t -> 0]
```

> `{{0, 0, -1}, {0, -1, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}}`

> `{{-(87/425), 0, -(416/425)}, {0, -1, 0}, {-(416/425), 0, 87/425}}`

etc.

**Original**

We can find an orthogonal matrix  satisfied $m^{T}\bullet m=\mathrm{Id},\mathrm{Det}(m)=1$ which transform $(0,1,0)$ to $(0,-1,0)$

```
m = Array[a, {3, 3}];
sol = Solve[{Transpose[m] . m == IdentityMatrix[3], 
     Det[m] == 1, {0, 1, 0} . m == {0, -1, 0}}][[1]];
m /. sol
({0, 1, 0} . m /. sol) == {0, -1, 0}
```

> `{{a[1, 1], 0, -Sqrt[1 - a[1, 1]^2]}, {0, -1,  0}, {-Sqrt[1 - a[1, 1]^2], 0, -a[1, 1]}}`

> `True`

For example we can set `a[1,1]->1/2`

> `{{1/2, 0, -(Sqrt[3]/2)}, {0, -1, 0}, {-(Sqrt[3]/2), 0, -(1/2)}}`

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't look like a generic method(maybe I missed your point). e.g. If I want to rotate from`{1, 0, 0}` to `{0, 1, 0}` then your method failed.

Comment: @ChrisGuo It also work. `m = Array[a, {3, 3}]; u = {1, 0, 0}; v = {0, 1, 0}; sol = 
 Solve[{Transpose[m] . m == IdentityMatrix[3], Det[m] == 1, 
    u . m == v}][[1]]; u . (m /. sol ) == v`

Comment: I still confused. If transforming from `{x1,y1,z1}` to `{x2,y2,z2}`, how could you solve the equations for `m`(it has 9 variables)?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, after reading the post in here: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180418/calculate-rotation-matrix-to-align-vector-a-to-vector-b-in-3d), I think maybe your method is a good workaround for this problem.

Answer (score 4):

This situation is another reason why I wrote the `vectorRotate[]` function in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/167114), which implements the method of [Möller and Hughes](https://doi.org/10.1080/10867651.1999.10487509):

```
vectorRotate[{0, 1, 0}, {0, -1, 0}]
   {{-1, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}
```