# Getting symbolic form of `RotationMatrix`

Tags: compile

Calling `Compile` seems to run into trouble compiling `RotationMatrix`, I'm guessing because it has type restriction to return unevaluated for symbolic arguments. Is there a technique to find the code used to compute `RotationMatrix` here?

```
d = 2;
b = 2;
Clear[v, theta, randomRotate, ran];
randomRotate = Compile[{{v0_, _Real, 1}, {theta_, _Real}},
   Module[{v2},
     v2 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], d];
     RotationMatrix[theta, {v0, v2}] . v0
     ];
   ];
theta = Pi/4;
A0 = Table[{1}~Join~ConstantArray[0, d - 1], b];
randomRotate[#, theta] & /@ A0
```

BTW, RandomVariate works for compilation, below a fast version of Gaussian sampler which works out of the box. This means the issue is with `RotationMatrix`

```
mu = 1;
gaussianSampler[diag_] := With[{d = Length[diag]},
   Compile[{{n, _Integer}},
    Module[{vals},
     vals = 
      mu + Sqrt[diag]*# & /@ 
       RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {n, d}]]]];
sampler = gaussianSampler[{1, 2}];
sampler[2]
```

Comment: `Compile[{{v0_, _Real, 1}, {theta_, _Real}}, 
 Module[{v2}, v2 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], d];
  RotationMatrix[theta, {v0, v2}] . v0],
 {{RotationMatrix[theta, {v0, v2}], _Real, 1}}
 ]` declares the type of `RotationMatrix`, but it seems neither `RandomVariate` nor `RotationMatrix` are compilable.

Comment: `RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]]` seems compilable, I used it to speed things up

Comment: I am not sure that I fully understand your question, but perhaps it could be helpful that you can precalculate the rotation matrix if you explicitly show the components of the $v_0$ and $v_2$ vectors: `RotationMatrix[theta, {Array[v0, 2], Array[v2, 2]}] . Array[v0, 2]`. The output looks complicated, but it likely could be greatly simplified with appropriate assumptions.

Comment: You need to make `d` an argument of the compiled function for `RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], d]` to be compilable. Have you seen ``CompiledFunctionTools`CompilePrint``?

Comment: I've added example of Compile working for random variate, errors given by `CompilePrint` seems to be vacuous

Comment: For compiled version of `RotationMatrix` see here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/161230/38178.