# Problem with convert matlab function into mathematica version of euler angle

Tags: matlab, rotation

I've wrote a function that will extract euler angle from matrix according to Matlab's function in AeroSpace toolbox's dcm2angle package file. But not quite right.

```
 threeaxisrot[r11_, r12_, r21_, r31_, r32_, r11a_, r12a_] :=  Module[{r1, r2, r3},  (*        % find angles for rotations about X, Y, and Z axes*)          r1 = ArcTan[ r11/ r12];          r2 = ArcSin[ r21 ];          r3 = ArcTan[ r31/ r32];   If[Abs[r21] >= 1, Print["HA-ha"]; r1 = ArcTan[r11a/r12a];    r2 = ArcSin[r21]; r3 = 0];  {r1, r2, r3}  ]       

Matrix2EulerAngleZXY[matrix0_] :=  Module[{dcm = matrix0},   threeaxisrot[-dcm[[2, 1]], dcm[[2, 2]], dcm[[2, 3]], -dcm[[1, 3]],    dcm[[3, 3]], dcm[[1, 2]], dcm[[1, 1]]]]
```

---

Matlab package directory in my computer is

```
"F:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\toolbox\\aero\\aero\\dcm2angle.m"
```

---

```
matrixList =  Table[RotationMatrix[i, {1, 0, 0}], {i, 0, 2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/6}]//N;

Matrix2EulerAngleTrackExpression // Definition

(*
    Matrix2EulerAngleTrackExpression[matrix0_,type_:ZXY]:=Module[{matrix=matrix0[[1;;3,1;;3]]}
,ttt=ToExpression[StringCases[StringReplace[ppp=MATLink`MEvaluate[[yaw, pitch, roll] = dcm
2angle(<>matrix2Matlab[N[Chop[matrix,1/10^5]]]<>,'<>type<>')],x:(NumberString~~e-~~NumberS
tring):>0],NumberString]]]
*)
```

Result1

---

This is the Matlab's result(good one).

```
Matrix2EulerAngleTrackExpression /@ matrixList

(*
    {{0,0,0},{0,-0.5236,0},{0,-1.0472,0},{0,-1.5708,0},{-3.1416,-1.0472,-3.1416},{-3.1416,-0.5
236,-3.1416},{-3.1416,0,-3.1416},{-3.1416,0.5236,-3.1416},{-3.1416,1.0472,-3.1416},{0,1.57
08,0},{0,1.0472,0},{0,0.5236,0},{0,0,0}}
*)
```

---

```
Matrix2EulerAngleZXY /@ matrixList

(*
    {{0.,0.,0.},{0.,-0.523599,0.},{0.,-1.0472,0.},{0.,-1.5708,0},{0.,-1.0472,0.},{0.,-0.523599
,0.},{0.,0.,0.},{0.,0.523599,0.},{0.,1.0472,0.},{0.,1.5708,0},{0.,1.0472,0.},{0.,0.523599,
0.},{0.,0.,0.}}
*)
```

Where goes wrong?

Do you have a robust euler angle function/package?

Comment: I use the MATLink package to calculate the angles before.

Comment: Apart from the other answers in this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29924/131, David Park´s `Presentations` package seems to deal with Euler angles: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30163/131

Answer (score 2):

More in-depth explanation of the math can be found at: http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/matrixToEuler/

```cpp
float yaw,pitch,roll=0.0f,epsilon=0.0001f;
if (m[1][0] > (1.0f-epsilon)) { // singularity at north pole
    yaw = atan2(m[0][2],m[2][2]);
    pitch = M_PI / 2.0f;
} else if (m[1][0] < -(1.0f-epsilon)) { // singularity at south pole
    yaw = atan2(m[0][2],m[2][2]);
    pitch = M_PI / -2.0f;
} else {
    yaw = atan2(-m[2][0],m[0][0]);
    pitch = asin(m[1][0]);
    roll = atan2(-m[1][2],m[1][1]);
}
return Vector3(yaw,pitch,roll);
```

You can of course switch handedness by transposing all the m[x][y] accesses.

Comment: Not exactly a *Mathematica* implementation...

Comment: He cross posted this to GameDev asking for a C/C++ implementation specifically. I had answered there but the moderators asked me to move it here.

Comment: Talk about convolution :-)

Comment: Yes, I asked here because I'd like a mathematica version. Can you make it the same result as my sample?

Comment: You have to do that much on your own, come on. I've even tested it against the transpose of the matlab spec.

Answer (score 2):

Let's call the two answers that you call the good one and the bad one q1 and q2. The difference is:

```
q1-q2
{{0., 0., 0.}, {0., 1.*10^-6, 0.}, {0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0}, {3.1416, 0., 3.1416}, {3.1416, 1.*10^-6, 3.1416}, {3.1416, 0.,   3.1416}, {3.1416, -1.*10^-6, 3.1416}, {3.1416, 0., 3.1416}, {0., 0., 0}, {0., 0., 0.}, {0., -1.*10^-6, 0.}, {0., 0., 0.}}
```

Looking through this, all the terms are either roundoff error (10^-6) or are Pi. So all you need do to make them match is to replace the near-Pi values with 0 (or vice versa).