# Using Rotation Matrix Data Applied to a Cube: Visualization

Tags: matrix, visualization, rotation

I've written a program that calculates the rotation matrices of a cube over time. The program outputs the matrices to a data file in the form of a series of Mathematica styled matrices (i.e. {{a11,a12,a13},...}}). They are separated by line breaks.

Here is my plan:

~Write a function that associates each matrix to some time t, sequentially.

~Write a function that multiplies a cube with center at origin by the current matrix in accordance with t.

~Write a final function that take output from the previous and visualizes it with a nice 'play' button.

This is my plan, but I'm not sure how to implement it -- I'm pretty new to Mathematica. I took a nice little tutorial, but it didn't cover quite something like this. I could use some help figuring this one out!

Thank you!

Comment: A simple example would be helpful. Don't post the entire data, but include a couple of time-slices, ideally with a smaller number of data points if the slices are actually huge. In addition, provide data for the cube (again ideally a small example).

Comment: One important detail is missing from the Q: are the times equally spaced? I just assumed they are in order to give an answer that could get you started. If not, interpolation may be an option.

Comment: The times are equally spaced, yes. Here are a few lines of the data output:
{{0.998024,-0.0628319,0},{0.0628319,0.998024,0},{0,0,1}},
{{0.992104,-0.125415,0},{0.125415,0.992104,0},{0,0,1}},
{{0.982264,-0.187503,0},{0.187503,0.982264,0},{0,0,1}},... etc.

These matrices are all of the form

{{cosx, -sinx, 0},{sinx, cosx, 0},{0,0,1}}.

Comment: Storing rotations as full matrices isn't very efficient... why not store just `x`? Anyway, you just have to replace `matrixList` in my answer by your list.

Comment: @Jens, at least the matrices are of certain structure here; at worst, one will still only need to store axis+angle…

Comment: (EDIT: Okay! I will try that. It will be... a very big list.)

I don't think I can store it like that -- each matrix is the result of multiplying the previous matrix by another which is obtained by solving the Moser-Veselov equation. (Q<sub>k+1</sub> = Q<sub>k</sub>F<sub>k</sub>) It varies with each iteration... and the solving program is written in C++ -- that's how I generated these matrices. What do?

Comment: "each matrix is the result of multiplying the previous matrix by another which is obtained by solving the Moser-Veselov" - you really ought to have mentioned stuff like that to begin with…

Comment: If you want to reduce the matrices to the axis-angle information for more efficient storage, you may want to look at [my answer here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29966/245).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing you're looking for something like this:

```
matrixList = 
  Table[EulerMatrix[{0, Pi t/2, 0}], {t, 0, 1, .1}];

frames = Table[
   Graphics3D[
    GeometricTransformation[Cuboid[{-1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}], 
     rotation], Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral", 
    PlotRange -> 1.5 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], {rotation, 
    matrixList}];

ListAnimate[frames]
```

Comment: …and the OP can use `RollPitchYawMatrix[]` instead if he so wishes…

Comment: @J.M. Or solve Euler's equations etc... I assumed the matrices already exist.