# Calculation of the desired Rotation Matrix

Tags: matrix, rotation

Here I have three orthogonal vectors, {-1,1,-1} {1,1,0} {-1,1,2}, and I want to obtain the rotation matrix which can transform these three vectors into {1,0,0} {0,1,0} {0,0,1}, respectively. Therefore, I tried:

```
Solve[{RotationMatrix[x1, {y1, y2, y3}].({-1, 1, -1}/
Norm[{-1, 1, -1}]) == {1, 0, 0}, 
RotationMatrix[x1, {y1, y2, y3}].({1, 1, 0}/Norm[{1, 1, 0}]) == {0, 1, 0},
RotationMatrix[x1, {y1, y2, y3}].({-1, 1, 2}/
Norm[{-1, 1, 2}]) == {0, 0, 1}}, {x1, y1, y2, y3}]
```

and

```
Solve[{EulerMatrix[{y1, y2, y3}].({-1, 1, -1}/
Norm[{-1, 1, -1}]) == {1, 0, 0}, 
EulerMatrix[{y1, y2, y3}].({1, 1, 0}/Norm[{1, 1, 0}]) == {0, 1, 0}, 
EulerMatrix[{y1, y2, y3}].({-1, 1, 2}/Norm[{-1, 1, 2}]) == {0, 0, 1}}, 
{y1, y2, y3}]
```

but neither of them works.

Can anyone help me to get the desired rotation matrix?

Comment: Try `Inverse[{{-1, 1, -1}, {1, 1, 0}, {-1, 1, 2}}]`

Comment: $0$ is a fixed point of this matrix, meaning that if it's a rotation, then it preserves the magnitude of vectors. So how can `{-1,1,-1}` be mapped to `{1,0,0}`?

Comment: The three vectors have to be normalized before  Inverse[] is applied.

Answer (score 2):

Does

```
frame = {{-1, 1, -1}, {1, 1, 0}, {-1, 1, 2}};
A = Orthogonalize[Transpose[frame]]
```

do what you seek for?

Comment: From here, one can use any of the methods in [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29924) to find the axis-angle representation of the rotation matrix.